# Example of sequence of continuous linear maps converging pointwise to zero without converging in norm

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm looking for a vector space $V$ and a series $(T_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $L(V,V)$ such that $T_n$ converges pointwise to zero, but the operator nom $||T_n||$ doesn't converge.

Comment: You want the operator norm not to have a limit at all, or to have a non-zero limit if it did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $T_n:l_p\to l_p$, $1\leq p<\infty$, $T_nx=(0,0,...,0,x_n,0,0,...)$. This sequence converges pointwise to the zero operator, but does not converge to the zero operator in the norm.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know any example using the space of bounded / continuous functions or something like this? I'm not familiar with $\mathcal{l}_p$ spaces.

Comment: For example, $A_nx=x(t+\frac{1}{n})-x(t)$ in $C[0,1]$. Вut here needs more difficult arguments (for example, for pointwise convergence, need to use the Banach-Steinhaus theorem). In my first example, everything turns out obviously.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I'll stick with you original answer.